# asp.net 4 url routing, how to access the route?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I'm using ASP.Net 4 URL routing on a web forms site.

I have multiple routes to a single page

`routes.MapPageRoute("","our-services", "~/Information.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("","our-company", "~/Information.aspx");`

On the destination page (Information.aspx) how can I tell which route was used to get there, for example was it from our-services or our-company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
HttpRequest.RawUrl
```

it should contain the original URL that was called (i.e. before the rewriting)

Answer (score 0):

From the information page, you could check who referred to it via Request.UrlReferrer.

HTH.